# Getting Error Uri from DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs

Tags: c#, webclient

Well basically I want to record the uri which produces an error when testing, using the debugger I can find the uri which failed, however I don't know how to retrieve it, here's a print screen below

http://img802.imageshack.us/img802/5465/progps.jpg

Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than call `WebClient.DownloadStringAsync(Uri)`, call the overload, `DownloadString(Uri, Object)`, passing the `Uri` as the second parameter.  Then, in the event handler, you can cast the value of `e.UserToken` to `Uri` to retrieve the value.  That is:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://example.com");
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadStringCompleted = StringDownloaded;
client.DownloadStringAsync(uri, uri);


void StringDownloaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Uri uri = (Uri)e.UserToken;

    ...
}
```

You can use this technique to pass any kind of state to the event handler.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thanks for the advice,  casting the UserState property as a Uri & overloading the DownloadStringAsync works perfectly (can't see UserToken)

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

What the comment by Ash on Jim Mischel's answer is saying is that the UserToken passed to DownloadStringAsync in the event handler function is accessible in e.UserState (e.UserToken doesn't exist on the DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs object e).

i.e. this works:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://example.com");
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadStringCompleted = StringDownloaded;
client.DownloadStringAsync(uri, uri);


void StringDownloaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e){
    Uri uri = (Uri)e.UserState;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(e.Error.Response as HttpWebResponse).ResponseUri
```

Comment: But won't ResponseUri be different from the requested Uri if there are redirects?